# Storing a variable in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a more of a theoretical question. I have a basic time-slots booking website where there is a model `time_slot.js`:

```
var mongoose = require ('../config/db');
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;


var timeSlotSchema = new Schema({
  start: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  end: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = {
  model: mongoose.model('TimeSlot', timeSlotSchema)
}
```

and I would like for the admin user to be able to define a max number of bookings to be done per time slot. My idea is to define a model to store the max number of orders the admin chooses then adding a counter variable for each time slot which increments with every order and decrements when the order is over.

However, I feel reluctant defining a model just to store a single variable (which also gets stored in a Mongodb collection all by itself). My question is: is there a better way to do it or is this a completely normal approach?

Comment: I'd still define it in the DB, in separate schema, maybe calling it e.g. `adminSettings` or so (and keep all similar setting-related data in it). 
Please always keep in consideration that your app could be expanded in the future- it's easier to write a few lines of code now and then expand than to rewrite much more if you decide not to store such vars in the DB.

If you really feel reluctant about keeping it in the DB and want to store it statically then simple JSON config kept in the root of your project (e.g. `config/admin.json`) could be enough. I'd still opt for the DB solution, though.

Comment: I don't think it would be very practical to keep the variable in a config file since the admin should be able to modify the variable as a user from the frontend of the website. So with this in mind, the schema solution seems more fitting for this scenario. Thanks!